# Jest Deleting snapshots when updating single test

Tags: jestjs

Im having a weird issue where Jest is deleting all snapshots when I am attempting to update a single test.

**if I have a directory:**

```
07/03/2018  11:05 AM           131,285 p-Error.ts.snap
07/03/2018  11:05 AM            75,741 p-Lot.ts.snap
06/29/2018  03:39 PM           134,879 p-Split.ts.snap
```

**and I run:**

```
npm test -- -i -u -t="p-Split"
```

**Here is the console output:**

```
PASS  src/__tests__/p-Split.ts (279.875s)r\openvrpaths.vrpath

 FAIL  src/__tests__/p-Error.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_scheduler.js:245:22

 FAIL  src/__tests__/p-Lot.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_scheduler.js:245:22
```

**and the directory now contains:**

```
06/29/2018  03:40 PM           134,879 p-Split.ts.snap
```

Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Snapshots are deleted because of the `-u` flag, which automatically removes unused/obsolete snapshots.

Why would you want to keep those snapshots, if you removed everything from the test files p-Error and p-Lot? If you removed p-Error and p-Lot test cases by accident, bring them back.

Comment: I still have tests in those other files, I am only trying to update the snapshots for the targeted testes in the p-Split files.  My assumption is that I could just run the p-split by using the -t command and update the snapshots in just those test cases using the -u command.

Comment: you could try running `npm test -- -i -u src/p-Split.ts`